# Alignment between material inside and outside a cases environment

Tags: horizontal-alignment, align, cases

In the code below, I'd like to make the `i=0,\ldots,n.` line up, in the output, with the cases in the first part of the definition. Ideally, the full-stop would align with the semicolons and comma.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
d_i(g_n,\ldots,g_0) &=
\begin{cases}
 (d_0g_ng_{n-1},g_{n-2},\ldots,g_0),& \text{if $i=0$;}\\
(d_ig_n,\ldots,d_1g_{n-i+1},d_0g_{n-i}g_{n-i-1},g_{n-i-2},\ldots,g_0), \\
   & \phantom{\text{if $i=0$;}}\llap{\text{if  $i=1,\ldots,n-1$;}} \\
  (d_ng_n,\ldots,d_1g_1),& \text{if $i=0$,}
 \end{cases}
\intertext{and}
  s_i(g_n,\ldots,g_0) &= (s_ig_n,\ldots,s_0g_{n-i},id_{G_{n-i}},g_{n-i-1},\ldots,g_0),\quad i=0,\ldots,n.
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Werner beat me by 56 seconds but an alternative scheme is

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
d_i(g_n,\ldots,g_0) &=
\begin{cases}
 (d_0g_ng_{n-1},g_{n-2},\ldots,g_0),& \text{if $i=0$;}\\
(d_ig_n,\ldots,d_1g_{n-i+1},d_0g_{n-i}g_{n-i-1},g_{n-i-2},\ldots,g_0), \\
   & \phantom{\text{if $i=0$;}}\llap{\text{if  $i=1,\ldots,n-1$;}} \\
  (d_ng_n,\ldots,d_1g_1),& \text{if $i=0$,}
 \end{cases}
\intertext{and}
  s_i(g_n,\ldots,g_0) &= (s_ig_n,\ldots,s_0g_{n-i},id_{G_{n-i}},g_{n-i-1},\ldots,g_0),&\llap{$i=0,\ldots,n$.\kern\minalignsep}
\end{align*}

\noindent X\dotfill X
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

The following provides what you're after:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}% http://ctan.org/pkg/mathtools

\begin{document}

\newsavebox{\mathbox}
\savebox{\mathbox}{$\left\{\begin{array}{@{}ll@{}}
  (d_ig_n,\ldots,d_1g_{n-i+1},d_0g_{n-i}g_{n-i-1},g_{n-i-2},\ldots,g_0), & \text{if $i=0$;} \\
  (d_ig_n,\ldots,d_1g_{n-i+1},d_0g_{n-i}g_{n-i-1},g_{n-i-2},\ldots,g_0), & \text{if $i=0$;} \\
  (d_ig_n,\ldots,d_1g_{n-i+1},d_0g_{n-i}g_{n-i-1},g_{n-i-2},\ldots,g_0), & \text{if $i=0$;}
\end{array}\right.\kern-\nulldelimiterspace$}
\begin{align*}
d_i(g_n,\ldots,g_0) &=
\begin{cases}
 (d_0g_ng_{n-1},g_{n-2},\ldots,g_0),& \text{if $i=0$;}\\
 (d_ig_n,\ldots,d_1g_{n-i+1},d_0g_{n-i}g_{n-i-1},g_{n-i-2},\ldots,g_0), \\
   & \phantom{\text{if $i=0$;}}\llap{\text{if  $i=1,\ldots,n-1$;}} \\
  (d_ng_n,\ldots,d_1g_1),& \text{if $i=0$,}
 \end{cases}
\intertext{and}
  s_i(g_n,\ldots,g_0) &= \makebox[\wd\mathbox][l]{$
    (s_ig_n,\ldots,s_0g_{n-i},id_{G_{n-i}},g_{n-i-1},\ldots,g_0),\hfill i=0,\ldots,n.
  $}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

The solution stores a bunch of math content inside a box called `\mathbox`. This box contains an `array` with column specification `@{}ll@{}` - similar to that of `cases`. Additionally it includes a left extensible brace `\left\{` (the null right delimiter `\right.` is removed using `\kern-\nulldelimiterspace`). The content in the `array` is constructed from the longest entry within the actual `cases` environment. I've used 3 of the same lines, although a single line with a zero-width vertical rule of sufficient length would also suffice. The intent is to provide an extensible left brace that is just as wide (horizontally) as the original `cases`, since only the width of `\mathbox` will be used.

Once the box is established, a regular `\makebox[\wd\mathbox][l]{$...$}` is used to set the content for the remaining math content.