# Align equal sign inside case with equal sign outside

Tags: align, cases

I want to align the equal sign inside the case with the equal sign outside. How to do that? I have read answers to these questions [1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/483234/align-text-in-a-cases-environment-with-text-outside) [2](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/453057/alignment-in-cases-with-text-outside-the-cases) [3](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/95947/alignment-between-material-inside-and-outside-a-cases-environment), but I'm still very clueless. Could anyone please help? Thanks!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}  
\begin{align*}
    v&=s\\
    \begin{cases}
    v'_x&=1\\
    v'_y&=2\\
    \end{cases}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: See this [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/621786/how-to-place-brace-on-the-right-of-a-subset-of-aligned-equations)?

Answer (score 3):

One way is drawing this set of equations:

```
\documentclass[border=5mm, preview]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,
                matrix}

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix (a) [matrix of math nodes, 
             nodes = {inner ysep=2pt},
             column sep=-4pt
             ]
{
v       & = s   \\
v'_x    & = 1   \\
v'_y    & = 2   \\
};
\draw[decorate,decoration={brace, mirror}] 
    (a-2-1.north -| a-3-1.west) -- (a-3-1.south west);
\end{tikzpicture}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I'm still a beginner. Let me try to understand it. :)

Comment: Image server seems to be working again ...

Comment: @JasperHabicht, thank you for info! Image added!

Answer (score 3):

A possibility with the `blkarray` package:

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{blkarray}
    \usepackage{amsmath}

    \begin{document}

    \[ \begin{blockarray}{r@{}l}
        v&{}=s\\
        \begin{block}{\{r@{}l}
        v'_x &{}=1\\
        v'_y&{}=2\\
        \end{block}
    \end{blockarray} \]

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Just adapt the code in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/621802/4427

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\[
\setlength{\arraycolsep}{0pt}
\begin{NiceArray}{r >{{}}c<{{}} l}
    v&=&s\\[1ex]
    v'_x&=&1\\[1ex]
    v'_y&=&2
\CodeAfter\SubMatrix\{{2-1}{3-3}.
\end{NiceArray}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]